# customize login.html of JBoss

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am developing a Java EE application using Jboss and the authentication.
I know JBoss has two files login.html and login-fail.html in order to use authentication.
The form in login.html file uses the action "j_security_check".
I was wondering if we could use this file but also if if we could develop our own action.

I would like to keep the action "j_security_check" but I would like to access my databse to set a session variable for example after a successful connection.

Answer (score 1):

The missing keyword you're looking for is "Custom JBoss Login Module" :)

There are various examples which shows [how to implement and integrate it](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/creating-a-custom-jboss-login-module) in your app.

There is also [JBoss documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Login_Modules.html#JBoss_Login_Modules) where your can get an overview of login modules already available in JBoss. [DatabaseServerLoginModule](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Login_Modules.html#sect-DatabaseServerLoginModule) is one of them and can probably be used with your database.

---

A simple demonstration of custom login page in a Servlet container can be found [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-form-authentication-with-tomcat.html?page=1).

In order to use your own login page with specific login module under JBoss do following:

1. Implement your own login page with 'j_security_check' action. BTW it's part of servlet API and is not JBoss specific.
2. Refer your login page in web.xml:

```xml
<login-config>          
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>         
  <form-login-config>    
          <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>    
          <form-error-page>/login-failed.jsp</form-error-page>      
  </form-login-config>  
</login-config>
```

3. Optional: Refer required login module in WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml if it's not used by default (login modules can be defined in standalone.xml)

```xml
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>org.example.YourSecurityDomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

4. Optional: deploy custom login module implementation within your application and register it in login-config.xml. Check [JBoss example](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Login_Modules.html#sect-Custom_LoginModule_Example) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've already used this module :) Indeed I've linked my database (including users with roles) with my jboss application. But it seems that in order to make it work, we have to use login.html provided by jboss (with the "j_security_check" action). The problem is that I would like to do other things when connecting. I would like to have some control on what login.html does.

Comment: "j_security_check" is not JBoss specific, it's part of Servlet API. You can deploy your own login page which uses this action. It will be intercepted by the container and redirected to the configured login module.

Comment: I agree with you, that's an interesting website thanks. However even the guy, who made the tutorial, hit the url to access his TestServlett. He just used the "j_security_check" action to use the authentification but once he's logged in he has to hit the url of his TestServlett to access it. We should automatically be redirected to this servlett.